# Como eliminar salto de linea entre comillas dobles?

Tags: java, regex, archivo

Estoy leyendo un archivo txt (de unos 8 millones de registros), linea por linea con `commons-io`,pero algunos datos estan asi:

```
"101010100"|"JOHN,,DOE"
"1010101001"|"ACME COMPANY
LOREM IPSUM"
"9999999111"|"JANE,,,DOE"
```

El formato se supone que debe ser una linea con los datos separados por pipes `|`, pero como pueden ver hay algunos que tiene un salto de linea y obviamente cuando leo la linea es diferente he estado tratando de quitar ese salto de linea pero no he podido lo que he hecho hasta el momento es:

1. Leer el archivo con un parser de csv
2. Probar expresiones regulares para eliminar el salto de linea
3. Pense que con hacer un split por `|` funcionaria, pero no porque como se va leyendo linea por linea no funciona.

Ninguna con resultado exitoso (la segunda me junto todo el texto), alguno tendra una idea de como puedo solucionar esto?

Estoy usando `Java 8`, `commonons-io` y probe `commons-csv` para el parser de csv

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Y si la segunda te juntó todo el texto, por qué no haces eso y luego un split por `|`? Sería una manera de empezar, y viendo que tienes líneas con saltos... diría que la más fácil

Comment: por que antes de procesar la línea valida que termine en comilla `"`, si no finaliza en comilla es que el resto de la información esta en la línea siguiente, de ser así, almacena la línea en variable temporal, lee la siguiente línea, la concatena con la temporal y posterior realiza lo que sea que haga el programa...

Answer (score 0):

Si todos los casos con como tu ejemplo el siguiente código debería funcionar:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        File f = new File("/ruta/al/archivo");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(nextLine(s));
        }
    }

    public static String nextLine(Scanner s) {
        // leer línea del archivo
        String line = s.nextLine();

        // si la línea no termina con " es porque tiene un salto de línea
        // entonces leer siguiente línea y concatenar para completar
        if (!line.endsWith("\"")) line += s.nextLine();

        return line;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: lo acabo de probar y funciona de maravilla, gracias!